Fredholm integral equation of the second kind using von neumann series
I am curious as to how one could go about proving that the Fredholm integral equation of the second kind has a unique solution using Von Neumann series. Specifically, given $g\in C([a,b])$ and $k:[a,b]\times[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ continuous, we have $$f(x)-\int_{a}^{b}k(x,y)f(y)dy=g(x)$$ and we can consider the operator $$Tz(x) = g(x)+\int_{a}^{b}k(x,y)f(y)dy$$ Assuming that we have $$\max_{x\in[a,b]} \int_{a}^{b}|k(x,y)|dy<1$$,how can one go about using Von Neumann series approach to show that there exists a unique solution $f\in C([a,b])$ to the Fredholm equation of the second kind? I am not really interested in computing the series necessarily, but just interested in how the series approach can be used to prove existence (by looking into what the operators are, for example).
I know that without Von Neumann series, existence can be proven using contraction theorem, and I was able to do that, but not sure how to do it using the Von Neumann series approach.

Let $$(Sf)(x)=\int\limits_a^bk(x,y)f(y)\,dy$$ Then $T=I-S.$ By assumption $\|S\|<1.$ Hence the equation $Tf=(I-S)f=g$ can be solved by the Carl Neumann (not John von Neumann) series $$f=(I-S)^{-1}g=\sum_{n=0}^\infty S^ng $$

That makes sense, but I just want to make sure -- by $S^n$ you mean n compositions of S? And the $||S||<1$ condition sufficiently shows that the Neumann series converges?

Yes, $S^n$ denotes the $n$-th composition. The series is absolutely convergent as $|S^n|\le |S|^n.$

May I know why we cannot do John von Neumann series? Why Carl?

The concept is due to Carl Neumann hence the credit should be given to him. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neumann_series
